# Color Meanings in Android Studio Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin, tdd

There are some blue, green, orange, yellow, and red lines when running tests on an Android Studio.

What is the meaning of each color?
They appear on both the Test class and the SUT.

[image: I mean where the red dot exists]

[image: On The Left Side of Android Studio There are Blue and Green Colors]

[image: Left side of the image with different colors]

Comment: Where is blue and green colors in the image?!

Comment: @MMG On the left side there are vertical blue and green lines.

Comment: That for Git control,Green means you added something, Blue means you altered something. You can click on it for details

Comment: And what about red?

Comment: @ChiChungLuk These vertical lines only exist on classes with a unit test on that method

Comment: Red is about Merge conflicts

Comment: @ramtintoosi what would you see if you click on it or hover it?

Comment: @ChiChungLuk It shows nothing, it has no relation to git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually two different types of lines in your screenshots.

The ones close to the thin vertical continuous line is about local changes to the file. Green means "new lines", blue means changed lines and a little arrow pointing towards the code means removed lines.

The colored lines further to the left are about code coverage. Green means that this line was executed (covered) and red means it was not executed.